# Python - saving issue while scraping (Selenium, Chrome Driver)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I've recently started learning Python.

I have a file of 1000 words for which I want to do direct searches on a website, and extract the number of results for each word on the search results page.

I'm using Selenium and Chrome Driver, on Mac.

My script runs well, manages to input the keyword, submit the search, retrieve the output and save it correctly, [c.f. screenshot of the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wS4AF.png).

However past a certain point, I have no idea why, [it starts saving the same output for a bunch of keywords](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PUitB.png).

Could that be due to wifi, Chrome driver? I have tried: Running the script while not using the computer, restarting my whole setup in between script runs, changing network, running the code in several batches, into smaller lists of keywords... I have no idea why it would stop behaving correctly past a certain point, would really appreciate any idea to solve this!

Script and imports below:

```
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import os
import time
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import selenium.webdriver.support.ui as ui
import selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions as EC
from tqdm.notebook import tqdm
import re


URL = "XXX"

# Add list of words i.e. pull from csv.
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
options.add_argument('--ignore-ssl-errors')
dir_path= '/Users/XXXXX/'
chromedriver = dir_path + "/chromedriver"

header_list=['Word']
words_df = pd.read_csv('/Users/XXXXX/results-file.csv', names=header_list)  
words_list = words_df.Word.tolist()

os.environ["webdriver.chrome?driver"] = chromedriver
# Start the Driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path = chromedriver)
# Hit the url and wait for 2 seconds.
time.sleep(2)
driver.get(URL)

# Empty dictionnary is created to store the data
dictionnary_numberresults = {}


for element in words_list[3000:10000]:

    # Enter word in searchbox, and wait for 4 seconds.
    
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']").clear()
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']").send_keys(element)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@id='twotabsearchtextbox']").submit()
    time.sleep(3)

    # Web page fetched from driver is parsed using Beautiful Soup.
    HTMLPage = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')
    Pagination = HTMLPage.find_all(class_="a-section a-spacing-small a-spacing-top-small")
    
    Number = re.findall('<span dir="auto">(.*)</span><span dir="auto">', str(Pagination), re.DOTALL)
    if re.findall('<span dir="auto">(.*)</span><span dir="auto">', str(Pagination), re.DOTALL) == []:
        Number = ['No results']
        
    dictionnary_numberresults[element] = Number[0]
```

Comment: 1) Have you tried searching manually for that keywords giving the same result? Is that giving not the same result?
2) Possibly after passing a big amount of searches the web page becomes more "busy"? Try adding some longer delay and see if this helps

Comment: 1) Yes, they all return different results. 2) I've tried yes, adding a couple different time.sleep() at different places (in between clear, send keys and submit; at the end of the loop) but it's not helping, keep having the same results "pasted" for batches of keywords

Comment: What's about giving longer delay?

Comment: @Prophet Unfortunately still facing the same issue even with longer delay... I've tried up to 10 seconds, and past a certain point it still ends up pasting the same results for all words

Comment: Try refreshing the page. If, for example, it works correctly for 45 searches and after that makes troubles make a refresh after each 30 searches. let me know if it helped. Generally i guess the browser / driver is not built to perform really large amount of sequential loop of searches.

Comment: @Prophet doing a refresh seemed to help, thank you! I also found out that the issue is due to my using my computer while the script is running, so when I leave my computer idle with the screen turned on and don't use it, it works perfectly fine.